# Time Complexity for removing the smallest value in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

What is the time complexity to remove the smallest value from an array with n elements that is sorted from smallest to largest?

I believe it is O(1) because the smallest value is the first value of the array, is this correct?

Comment: define "remove"

Comment: Yes, depends of your model. I guess if you have the C point of view, you just have to shift the array pointer.

Answer (score 4):

It is O(n), because after removing the element, all other elements need to be moved 1 place to the left.

If you would have a Linked List, this would not be necessary, so for this data structure it would be O(1).

Comment: Arrays provide random access if you remember ;)

Comment: Even with a single linked list, it's O(1).

Comment: I never said it wasn't, but I edited my answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

To remove an element from an array you have first to **find** it, which in your case takes `O(1)` because: `smallest = array[0]`

However removing it will require your to shift all elements from `n` to `n-1`, which will require going through the whole array and shifting elements.

```
int* removeSmallest(int *arr)
{
    //int smallest = arr[0]; // O(1)

    //shift elemts
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)-1; i++) // O(n)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i+1];
    }

    return arr;
}
```